# drop duplicate data in a data frame under special condition using pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a the following data frame:
[image]

I want to remove duplicate data in WD column, if they have the same drug_id.

For example, there is two "crying" in WD column with the same drug_id = 32. So I want to remove one of the row that has crying.

How I can do it? I know how to duplicate rows, but I do not know how to add this condition to this code. 
df = df.apply(lambda x:x.drop_duplicates())

Comment: By the way Mary... I'd upvote this question if it had data I could copy and paste rather than a picture of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drop_duplicates` with `subset` parameter which optionally considers certain columns for duplicates:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["drug_id", "WD"])
```

If the upper/lower cases are important for considering duplicates, you could try:

```
df[~df[['drug_id', 'WD']].apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()).duplicated()]
```

Where you can convert both `drug_id` and `WD` columns to lower case, use `duplicated()` method to identify duplicated rows and then use the generated logical series to filter out duplicated rows.

---

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,2,2], "B":[1,2,3,4], "C":[1,1,2,3]})

df
#   A   B   C
#0  1   1   1
#1  1   2   1
#2  2   3   2
#3  2   4   3

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'C'])
#   A   B   C
#0  1   1   1
#2  2   3   2
#3  2   4   3
```

Comment: how about this for a stop gap `df.assign(WD=df.WD.str.lower()).drop_duplicates(subset=["drug_id", "WD"])`

Comment: @piRSquared That's a nice one. I am having a slightly different version.